# How do I set the default bigquery dialect in Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

In datalab I'm using the datalab.bigquery module. I'd like to set the default dialect to SQL.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
import datalab.bigquery as datalab_bq
dialect=datalab_bq.Dialect.default()
dialect.set_bq_dialect('sql')
```

But it doesn't seem to have changed the dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the global `set_datalab_bq_dialect` method to set the dialect, it accepts either `standard` or `legacy`.

Please note that Datalab is moving away from supporting the `datalab` package in favor of the new `google.datalab` package, which only supports standard BigQuery dialect and does not use this global method.